# Authentification application mobile ionic avec symfony 3

Tags: symfony, mobile, ionic-framework, fosuserbundle

How do I create a token and send it with SYMFONY 3.1 for authentication of a mobile application developed by Ionic. I used FOSUserBundle for authentication in the web server. Then normally I use RestFul, but I have not found a clear document.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post questions in English only, Stackoverflow requires English questions; otherwise your question will get closed.

Comment: Hello,How do I create a token and send it with SYMFONY 3.1 for authentication of a mobile application developed by Ionic. I used FOSUserBundle for authentication in the web server. Then normally I use RestFul, but I have not found a clear document.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is Ionic expecting at a token? Can you show some sample code or a link? I updated your post to English which is what you should have done.

Comment: I have not yet found a solution for authenticating the mobile application. I'm still looking for the right solution. 
After a little research I found that I have to use RESTFul api. But I have not found a clear documentation for authentication.

Comment: I Voted to close as it's an off-topic question for StackOverflow (_and it's also stated by OP in his comments as a tutorial request_). For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a token for authentication I recommend to use JWT tokens. Each token is generated when a user logins through the RestfulAPI and then the ionic app saves the token (common to save it on localStorage) and then the ionic app sends the token in every request to validate the session.

Make sure to return a JsonResponse to make your API.

Also here it is a bundle for [JWT](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)

Comment: I have not successfully installed JWT bundle. you have a tutorial clair ? 

Thanks